# How to hide Mutual Friends from others on Facebook ?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

The new Timeline allows you to hide the friends list by going to friends tab and change the privacy to "Only me", but it still shows those friends in common .

Is there a way I can hide them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there is no control to hide this, it will only show a mutual friend to someone if one of the two people's friend lists are already visible.  So if you hide your friend list, someone visiting your timeline will only see mutual friends that have their friend list visible to that person.  So although Facebook makes it easier, the visitor can already tell that you and their other friend are friends by checking their other friend's friend list.  If Facebook did not already display it, someone could just write a script to get the same information.

Comment: This is not true I have a friend in another country who IS NOT friends with anyone on my facebook so there is not mutual friends and I cannot hide my list from him and it has cause me grief since I have male friends so I am not able to hide this list at all from anyone . I am at the point I am going to close out my facebook since I have no privacy.

Comment: @kelly: Why can't you hide your friends from this person?  Did you go to your timeline » Friends » Edit and change the visibility to Only Me?  It is only the list of mutual friends that you may be unable to hide, but if you have no mutual friends then that would not be an issue.  You can hide your other friends from anyone except yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Mutual friends cannot be hidden. That defeats the purpose of having them with someone. Only 2 people can see them: you & your friend with whom you have mutual connections.