# How to completely hide my profile on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I have a timeline profile on Facebook.

1. I want to hide it completely from any search results. Maybe show it only to people to whom I give direct link.
2. I don't want my friends to see the mutual friends we have got.

I think (1) is possible and I saw (2) is possible

How would it be possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot hide your Facebook completely from search results, you *can* limit who can find you by your phone number or email address.

*Why?*

> Your name, gender, username, and user ID (account number), along with
>   your profile picture, cover photo, and networks (if you choose to add
>   these) are available to anyone. This is because this information is
>   essential to helping you connect with your friends and family.

To limits who can see your friends go to `http://www.facebook.com/<yourusername>/friends` click Edit and change to "Only Me", but there are still issues see more at [How to hide Mutual Friends from others on Facebook ?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23489/how-to-hide-mutual-friends-from-others-on-facebook)