# Can I prepare a Facebook profile completely off-public?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

I want to prepare my new Facebook profile **completely off-public**, and publish it once it will be ready (in my opinion). Is it possible?

I've read [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/26539/21486) and assuming, that my new profile (account) will have (in the beginning -- in so called *private phase*) 0 friends, I assume that this is first step. I have also read [this question + answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/25220/21486) on about hiding certain data from searching.

I have set another (test) Facebook's profile, so if anyone not logged-in access it, he or she sees only `This content is currently unavailable`. But once someone is logged in, he or she sees a whole lot of unnecessary (from my point of view) things (photo, cover or recent activity as well as friends and likes -- if they exists).

It is extremely essential (for project's success), that **nothing** from my profile information (devoted to this project) is available / searchable / revealed to anyone before official "openning" (so called *public phase*). So, I'd like to ask, if there is *anything else*, I can undertake to protect my profile from anyone until it goes public?

Comment: That’s effectively not possible at the moment; your profile foto is public no matter what. And they are [killing the possibility to opt-out of search](http://techcrunch.com/2013/10/10/facebook-search-privacy/).

Comment: The best you can hope for is to set the privacy settings to each section of your profile to "Only me".

Comment: Thanks guys! Please, reformulate these to a full-size answers, so I can pick one of us and give you some reps (if you care).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s effectively not possible at the moment—your current profile photo and your cover image are public no matter what.

They are killing the possibility to opt-out of search as well. Check [this](http://techcrunch.com/2013/10/10/facebook-search-privacy/) TechCrunch article for more info on the subject.

So, to answer you question, I’d say that you should not set a profile photo and cover image before the “opening”. And maybe use a fake name as well.

But the way I see it (and the way it is now), you’ll have a lot of work to do just before the “opening,” in order to reverse every “Only me” setting back to a more public option. Because, as Krampus was saying in his comment, you *will have to* set every bit of info to “Only me” in order to make sure your profile is “hidden”.